# How can i change the color of navbar while changing the width of the screen in Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

For eg: suppose if i use navbar-dark and bg-dark in nav tag, i want to change it to navbar-light and bg-light when i change screen width to say around 600px 
(In Bootstrap 4)

Answer (score 3):

Use CSS media queries to solve this problem.
Example Code Here:

```css
@media (max-width: 600px) {
 .navbar-dark.bg-dark{
    background-color: #ddd !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar w/ text</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarText" aria-controls="navbarText" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarText">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <span class="navbar-text">
      Navbar text with an inline element
    </span>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks its working now ,didnt knew we need to add !important

Comment: It is working? beacuse you are just overwriting the bg color of the bootstrap css rule , and text color are changing to black?

Comment: the background color is changing perfectly but the text-color isnt changing

Answer (score 2):

In the bootstrap.css file add the media query on the .navbar-dark section and then
add the .navbar-dark class on your navbar with .navbar-light and it will trigger the dark only at 600+ px

```
@media (min-width: 600px) {
  .navbar-dark .navbar-brand {
    color: #fff;
  }

  .navbar-dark .navbar-brand:hover, .navbar-dark .navbar-brand:focus {
    color: #fff;
  }

  .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  }

  .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:focus {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
  }

  .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link.disabled {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
  }

  .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .show > .nav-link,
  .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .active > .nav-link,
  .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link.show,
  .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link.active {
    color: #fff;
  }

  .navbar-dark .navbar-toggler {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  }

  .navbar-dark .navbar-toggler-icon {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 30 30' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath stroke='rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)' stroke-width='2' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' d='M4 7h22M4 15h22M4 23h22'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  }

  .navbar-dark .navbar-text {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  }

  .navbar-dark .navbar-text a {
    color: #fff;
  }

  .navbar-dark .navbar-text a:hover, .navbar-dark .navbar-text a:focus {
    color: #fff;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use media queries and define your breakpoint as 600px and apply new classes.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/238893/)

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px){
  .navbar{
    background-color:darkred;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    .navbar{
    background-color:red;
  }
}
```